# ng-change is not calling the method and no errors are shown

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on angularjs application. I have a radio buttons, based on the selection of radio button I need to show the results.
Issue is when I change the radio button,  it's not calling the js code.Unable to trace the error/issue and no errors are shown on the console.
Below I'm sharing the entire code, any suggestions would be helpful.

html:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    One <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change='newValue(value)'> <br>
    Two: <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="bar" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't recognize your `ng-model` or `ng-change` because your `<tr>` doesn't contain any `<td>`. Simply wrap your `inputs` in a `<td>` and it should work:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        ALL <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change='newValue(value)'> <br>
        Laptop,desktop,server: <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="bar" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the explanation for this reason? Is Angular somehow simulating the node validity?